# DelayedJob Worker not configured by rails initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

**What is the correct way to initialize a rails application state so that the DelayedJob workers (as well as the rails application) are affected by that initialization?** I'm having trouble where application configuration set up in my rails initializers don't seem to be visible to my DelayedJob jobs.

I have several 'service' observable/singletons that I orchestrate in a rails initializer like (this is a contrived example):

```rb
# my_app_initializer.rb
puts 'initializing my app...' # this DOES get logged in DJ worker

ShopActivityService.instance.add_observer(NotificationService.instance, func=:handle_shop_activity)

# if someone calls ShopActivityService.do_activity(), notification service sends an email
```

The idea is that whenever there is some 'shop activity', the 'notification service' sends out an email or something.

**The problem is** that if a delayed job worker invokes the `ShopActivityService`, the NotificationService does not seem to be registered as an observer and so it does not get notified.

I have noticed that the initializer is invoked when I start the application with `rails jobs:work`, but the code in the job itself must be run from some other environment or context?

**edit:** a simpler way of demonstrating the problem:

```
# my_job.rb
class MyJob
  @@x = 0
  def self.inc_x
    @@x = @@x + 1
  end
  def self.print_x
    puts "x is #{@@x}"
  end

  def self.schedule_job
    new.delay.execute_job
  end

  def execute_job
    self.class.print_x
  end
end

# my_job_initializer.rb
MyJob.inc_x
```

then in a `rails console` this has unexpected results:

```
MyJob.print_x
# prints 'x is 1' as expected

MyJob.schedule_job
# the delayed job worker process prints 'x is 0'
```

**edit 2:** I have asked this question on the [DJ group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/delayed_job/hgZvJtydLWs) and created a small github project demonstrating the problem: https://github.com/cechner/dj_test

Answer (score 2):

A kind poster on the Delayed Job group helped me out: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/delayed_job/hgZvJtydLWs

To summarise, rails in development mode does 'code reloading' on all code running in the `app/` directory by default. It does not however reload code in the `config/initializers/` directory. So my services were being reloaded (and hence the observers were being cleared) but the initialisation that orchestrates those services (by registering the observers) was not being re-run.

I am aware of the problem with using singletons to share global state, but I am not sure what the 'correct' or community approved approach is for orchestrating services at runtime.

For now I have solved the problem with the following:

```
# config/initializers/my_application_config.rb
module MyApplication
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # was previously doing config.after_initialize, but to_prepare seems to be called every time a reload happens
    config.to_prepare do
      ServiceOrchestrator.prepare
    end
  end
end

# app/services/service_orchestrator.rb
class ServiceOrchestrator
  def self.prepare
    # clear because this seems to be invoked twice every reload for some reason
    ShopActivityService.instance.delete_observers

    ShopActivityService.instance.add_observer(NotificationService.instance, func=:handle_shop_activity)
  end
end
```